# Repeating cell based on X values on a row and move to the next row and do same process

Tags: google-sheets

I have this data and each row contains X row number in a cell, so I want to repeat the email and other values on the row based on the X number in the cell.

so for example, if the X value is 0 I don't want this row to move to the other sheet, but if the value is 4 I want to have to the other sheet 4 times. and then continue with the next rows.

I actually could achieve this but the issue is that I don't know how to make the formula move to the next rows and do the same process.

[image]

Link for the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VbOyaMfsbS6Yoz9xUqfNkLqmPyzMxd-K97Dc7vywLm0/edit?usp=sharing

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this formula in `I6` of your sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, REPT(C6:C10&";", D6:D10)), ";")))`

See if this is what you are looking for.